# Primitive operations and running time

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures

For the given pseudo code I have to determine primitive operations and running time:

```
for( i=0; i<n; i++)            ->1+n+n=2n+1
   a[i] = 0;                   ->?
for( i=0; i<n; i++ )           ->2n+1
   for( j=0; j<n; j++ )        ->n(2n+1)
     a[i] += a[j] + i + j;     ->?
```

Anyone to help me if it's correct and how to do the rows which I have put ?. please

Comment: Are you trying to figure out the run time complexity?

Comment: time complexity yes

Comment: It is quadratic. O(n^2)

Comment: Assigning values doesn't add up to any complexity. (first ?)

Comment: Primitive operations are with ->

Comment: I get the + 1, but I don't understand the n+n in `1+n+n`, what's the meaning of summing up two times n for a loop that executes for n times?

Comment: How do you define a "primitive operation"? This term doesn't appear in the C++ standard, so it's unclear what exactly you mean by it.

Comment: Exactly. Also consider removing or re-stating the other term 'running time' (use a suitable term like 'time complexity'). If you wanted the exact time (as per the system, say) then you'd have to run benchmarks for your segment of code using functions from a suitable library like `chrono`.

Comment: In addition to defining "primitive operation", it would be helpful to justify / explain how you got the counts you have. Why `1+n+n`? Why `2n+1`? Why `n(2n+1)`? These would at least serve as examples of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Example of an example (a.k.a. why definitions are important): while I do have a guess as to how you got your counts, that guess does not cover the subscript operator. The line `a[i] = 0` has two operators -- subscript and assignment. Are both primitive? Should this line be counted as `1` or `2` (or something else?) times the number of times it executes? Having a definition of "primitive operation" would allow such questions to be answered.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, the for loop instruction going from 0 to `n` times would be executed `n+1` times (once extra when loop index equals `n` itself, after which it breaks), so it would be `n+1` and not `2n+1`. Its contents would run for `n` times. Assigning values doesn't add additional complexity in terms of input size (`n`):

```cpp
for(i = 0; i < n; i++)   // 1+n 
   a[i] = 0;            // runs for n times
```

Likewise, for the nested loops, the inner-loop statement will run for `n+1` times, multiplied by `n`, as it in itself is the content of the outer loop, making the product of `n(n+1)`. The contents would run for `n*n` times.

```cpp
for(i = 0; i < n; i++)          // n+1
   for(j = 0; j < n; j++)      // n(n+1) => n*n+n
       a[i] += a[j] + i + j;  // runs for n*n, for the dominant factor
```

With the innermost statements running for `n*n` times, the overall asymptotic time complexity would be O(n<sup>2</sup>).

Comment: This is a good example of why questions need to be clarified before they can be reasonably answered. The OP probably does not see the `for` loop instruction as a single "primitive" operation. The OP probably looked at the `for` loop and saw `1` assignment, `n` comparisons, and `n` increments, expressed as `1+n+n` "primitive" operations.  Probably. This does assume that the OP made a mistake, since there are in fact `n+1` comparisons, not `n`.

Comment: @JaMiT Gotcha, that count makes sense following your breakdown. And right, unless the OP states what counts as primitive operations, it is ambiguous.